# The school is open from 10 A.M to 5 P.M

Tags: verbs, adjectives, passive-voice, aspect, semantics

I know that **open** is an ergative verb and it can be used transitively and intransitively and **open** is also an adjective.

> **The school opens at 10 A.M  and closes at 5 P.M.**
>
> **The school is opened at 10 A.M  and is closed at 5 P.M**.
>
> **The school is open from 10 A.M to 5 P.M.**

I think all the sentences are possible and grammatical.If they are wrong, why are they wrong?

I would like to know if any one of these sentences is wrong or is there any difference among them?

Comment: I for one think the first two are incorrect - unidiomatic at best. The third is fine.

Comment: The school *"opens"* **at** 10 am and remains open till 5 pm.

Comment: The second is a bit strange - **is** open**ed**?

Comment: @AIQ.I have edited my question.Even though my question, I would like to have an answer for my question

Comment: After your edit, all three are grammatical and possible depending on the context. We often hear 1 and 3 - they are common usage. The second needs a special context - I can't think of a scenario at the moment where I would use (2) over (1).

Comment: @AIQ.Some duplicate questions are upvoted and a question like mine is down voted. What do you think is the reason.is the way of the users mysterious?

Comment: I haven't downvoted.  But the problem with the question is that you have no problem.  You say "Here are three sentences. I think they are correct."  We think "That's great, go and use them."  As the question is written you don't say what your problem is.   Why do you ask about these sentences (and not the thousands of other sentences that you think are correct).  What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

All three sentences are grammatically correct and would be understood by an English speaker.
The second one is far less common, because it implies focus on the act of opening and closing.

If all you're trying to communicate is when the school will be open, use the first or third sentence.
If you have a reason to convey exactly when the change happens from closed to opened (and vice versa), use the second form.